# How to remove hash from URL in Angular5?

Tags: angular, jboss

Angular Routing(In my app-routing.module.ts)

```
@NgModule({
    exports: [ RouterModule ],
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
    declarations: []
})
```

In index.html I have added `<base href="/">`

But in the URL I can see the `#`
My application is deployed on JBoss AS 7.1.1 Server

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#hashlocationstrategy

Comment: Add the <base> element just after the <head> tag.

Answer (score 1):

In your app module do this. Find more information in [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#hashlocationstrategy) about hash location strategy.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
  // other imports
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: false })
  ],
  declarations: [
  ],
  providers: [

  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I doubt this is the case