# How to get current route in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I'm using `{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },` in my `app.module.ts`. But when I give `this.route.url` it always contains `/` whether I'm in `/home` or `/dashboard` or `/profile`

I need to get the particular route value

`constructor(public router:Router) {} alert(this.router.url);`

Answer (score 15):

**Not sure if this applies to v5, but may help anyway**

You can also subscribe to router event NavigationEnd, this seems to be the best way to always get the current url.

**important notes:**
- make sure you place this code in the `contructor()` of the `app.component.ts` file, in order to always get the last url value.

```js
// file: src/app/app-component

  export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router) {

    // listen to events from Router
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        // event is an instance of NavigationEnd, get url!  
        const url = event.urlAfterRedirects;
        console.log('url is', url);
      }
    })

  }
}
```

Comment: This comes with the params attached.

Comment: Works for Angular 9. Thanks @guillefd

Answer (score 9):

Your `route` instance should be from `Router`

```
constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) { }

this.router.url // this must contains your full router path
```

Comment: Yeah I'm using the same

Comment: So are you getting URL properly?

Comment: No. I'm getting only /

Comment: I guess you were on root path so you getting `/` only

Comment: Ohh Got it. If I use this.router.url in dashboard.component.ts on init then I'm getting as /dashboard. If I use that in header oninit I'm getting only /. Can I get /dashboard everywhere

Comment: How will you get `dashboard` everywhere, you only get if you are on that route

Comment: Is there any way?

Comment: No this is not possible, may be you are not clear with what you are asking

Comment: Thanks. Can u check this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49892407/how-to-remove-hash-from-url-in-angular5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173370/discussion-between-pardeep-jain-and-krishna).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want hash to be part of URL make to use hash false as shown in below code :

```
  RouterModule.forRoot([
  {path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent},
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent},
], {useHash: false}),
ProductModule,
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Added useHash : false but still hash exits in my URL